# Remove product (item) from WooCommerce checkout page using AJAX

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, checkout

I have added a removal link to the checkout for each product. This part works fine. Problem is; upon removal, the page is "scrolled to top".

I would like to change this by adding AJAX to the removal process. I've tried, but without success. In other words; when clicking on the removal link, the refresh should happen in the background and the customer stays on the same section.

**This is the code I am working with:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'link_to_remove_item_from_checkout', 20, 3 );
function link_to_remove_item_from_checkout( $quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    $remove_item = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf (
    '<a style="text-decoration:underline" href="%s" rel="nofollow" title="Remove from Order" class="remove-product-from-checkout">Remove</a>',
    esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_item_key)),
    __('Remove from Order', 'woocommerce'),
    esc_attr($cart_item['product_id']),
    esc_attr($cart_item['data']->get_sku())
    ), $cart_item_key);

    return '<br><strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf('<b>Qty:</b> %s', $cart_item['quantity']) . '</strong> '.$remove_item.'<br clear="all">';
}


add_action('wp_ajax_woo_get_ajax_data', 'remove_product_from_checkout');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_get_ajax_data', 'remove_product_from_checkout');
function remove_product_from_checkout() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['$remove_item']) ) {

        $remove_product = sanitize_key( $_POST['$remove_item']);

        WC()->session->set('product_id', $remove_product);

    echo json_encode($remove_item);
}
    die();
}
```

**This is the script which I am not sure how to modify to make this work with a link.**

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'script_for_removing_product_on_checkout', 10, 0);
function script_for_removing_product_on_checkout(){
if (!is_checkout()) return;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( function($){
$('form.checkout').on('change', 'remove_product', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var p = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
data:{
'action': 'woo_get_ajax_data',
'packing': p,
},
success: function (result){
$('body').trigger('update_checkout');
},
error: function(error){
}
});
});
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains some mistakes.

To remove a product (item) from checkout using AJAX, you can use:

```php
// Concatenate remove link after item qty
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $remove_link = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
    sprintf(
        '<a href="#" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s">&times;</a>',
        __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
        esc_attr( $cart_item['product_id'] ),
        esc_attr( $cart_item['data']->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( $cart_item_key )
    ),
    $cart_item_key );

    // Return
    return $item_qty . $remove_link;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );

// jQuery - Ajax script
function action_wp_footer() {
    // Only checkout page
    if ( ! is_checkout() )
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($) {
        $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'click', '.cart_item a.remove', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            var cart_item_key = $( this ).attr( "data-cart_item_key" );
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'woo_product_remove',
                    'cart_item_key': cart_item_key,
                },
                success: function ( result ) {
                    $( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
                    //console.log( 'response: ' + result );
                },
                error: function( error ) {
                    //console.log( error );
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer', 10, 0 );

// Php Ajax
function woo_product_remove() { 
    if ( isset( $_POST['cart_item_key'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_key = sanitize_key( $_POST['cart_item_key'] );
        
        // Remove cart item
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
    }
    
    // Alway at the end (to avoid server error 500)
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woo_product_remove', 'woo_product_remove' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_product_remove', 'woo_product_remove' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
    function lp_woocommerce_checkout_remove_item( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( is_checkout() || is_cart() ) {
        $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

        $remove_link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">×</a>',
            esc_url( WC()->cart->wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
            __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
            esc_attr( $product_id ),
            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
        ), $cart_item_key );

        return '<span>' . $remove_link . '</span> <span>' . $product_name . '</span>';
    }

    return $product_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'lp_woocommerce_checkout_remove_item', 10, 3 );
```